# mirror to a transformed files' structure

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, pax

I'd like to **synchronize** a files structure to another, but **transformed** one, eg:

```
filesStructureA/ --[transformation(T)]--> filesStructureB/
```

Is it possible doing this with `rsync`? I saw rsync accept a list of files as input (`--files-from`), but don't really know how to apply the transformation T for each of one...

In other words, is it possible with rsync to rename files on the fly ?

Thank you.

—

for an example, from `src/` to `dst/`, suppress every `bar/` occurences in the destination path, eg:

```
src/foo/hi.txt
src/foo/bar/hey.txt
src/foo/bar/bar/lorem/bar/hoy.txt

sed 's/bar\///'          <- [Transformation function]

dst/foo/hi.txt
dst/foo/hey.txt
dst/foo/lorem/hoy.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is [pax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_%28Unix%29):

```
cd src/
find . -type -f -path '*bar/*' -print0 | pax -0 -rw -v -Y -Z -s '/\/bar//g' ../dst/
cd ..
```

Comment: nice, I never hear of pax.  Still confused about the exact use case (do you always have bar in the source?)